# Recommendations for well-known example where "UX" decision improved conversion rate?

Tags: user-behavior, research, marketing, conversion-rate

I have to present the value of UX to a room full of marketing people. I have the very-well documented ROI stating that well designed interfaces = increased customer satisfaction = reduced cost of ownership and support = increased sales via word of mouth, etc.

I've been asked to add an engagement slide documenting a well-known example where a UX decision led to "massive increases in conversion rate". The first thing coming to mind are the many examples where shortening forms dramatically increased completion - but I'm being asked for something more like "so-and-so changed the button to red and sales went through the roof!"

It could also be an example of a UX guru knowing the users so well than a terminology change or the like had a similar effect.

I know that's kind of vague and really isn't representative or giving enough credit to the field (and crosses well into CRO) but if anyone has anything coming to mind or that was asked for something similar I could use a suggestion. TIA --

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one answer! Thank you everyone for your valuable help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is really easy: **conversion improvement is based on UX**, because it's based on *testing, research, analysis, auditing and deployment based on all of these techniques* (between others) in which **Marketing is just one of those techniques**. And I have a Marketing degree, so believe me I'm not putting down marketing, just considering everything on perspective

Now, if you want cases and info, there are LITERALLY THOUSANDS OF PAGES about this subject. Just not to bore anyone, here you have a few links

## Numbers (or HOW)

- https://econsultancy.com/blog/63984-conversion-rate-optimisation-eight-case-studies-that-show-the-benefit-of-ux-testing/
- http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/20566/The-Button-Color-A-B-Test-Red-Beats-Green.aspx
- http://www.usertesting.com/blog/2014/10/22/usability-tests-tripled-lead-generation-conversion-rates/
- http://blog.usabilitytools.com/6-steps-usability-testing-to-conversion/

## Rationale (or WHY and then HOW)

- http://www.nngroup.com/articles/conversion-rates/
- http://conversionxl.com/great-user-experience-ux-leads-to-conversions/

or if you don't want to read all this, just take a look to this video featuring **Willy Lai** from *Sansung, Paypal, AOL, Apple* and there goes the list (warning, it's a full hour of examples!):

http://aquent.com/extra/webcast/ux-for-roi?showThank=1&result=success&src=wcst_14_10_ama_mplander&aqvt=aq

Well, hope you have enough to convince your colleagues! ;)

Comment: +1 Great and well researched answer, I've bookmarked it just for the links!

Answer (score 4):

## The $300 Million Button

So you want a case of "so-and-so changed the button and sales went through the roof"? Well I think this is as close as you'll get, it comes with a snazzy title and all.

[The $300 Million Button](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button)

[Backstory](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2011/10/17/the-back-story-for-the-300-million-button/)

> It's hard to imagine a form that could be simpler: two fields, two buttons, and one link. Yet, it turns out this form was preventing customers from purchasing products from a major e-commerce site, to the tune of $300,000,000 a year.
>
> The designers fixed the problem simply. They took away the Register button.
>
> The results: The number of customers purchasing went up by 45%. The extra purchases resulted in an extra $15 million the first month. For the first year, the site saw an additional $300,000,000.

Unfortunately the article never discloses who this major e-commerce site is so use these statistics at your own risk, but I'd say it hits the nail on the head for a rags to riches UX success story.

Comment: Wouldn't that be Amazon?

Comment: @Dover that would be my first thought as well that's just speculation on my part

Answer (score 2):

In addition to some great links provided by Devin, I would also like to point out this [45 minute video by Leah Buley about modern UX organization.](http://ixda.org/resources/leah-buley-modern-ux-organization) She has discussed many important points like:

- Conversion rates and UX
- Role of UX in driving valuations of companies like Slack and AirBnB
- Different kinds of UX design processes and how they affect revenues,
  teams and products
- Why User Research plays a key role in developing world-class products?
- What you should do to build a design-driven company?

It's a highly data focused talk and can help you to refine your pitch.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.